# Увеличить яркость в камере AVFoundation

Tags: ios, камера, avfoundation

Разрабатываю приложение "камера ночного видения", использую AVFoundation для создания камеры. Что я сделал: увеличил экспозицию путем увеличения ISO, изменил баланс белого, установив параметр tint в -150 и поставив параметру temperature 2000. Получается зеленый экран, но я не могу сделать его светлее, я думал увеличивать время затвора, установив его, например, в 1/10, но я не уверен что под все камеры этот параметр будет работать стабильно. Скачал некоторые приложения из app store чтобы посмотреть на их работоспособность, там экран получается более светлый, как мне добиться подобного результата? Может сталкивался кто-либо с подобной частью разработки. Прикрепил скрины других программ и своей программы, если нужно скинуть код, то скину, просто он большой, точно не знаю что именно нужно скинуть.
Приложение из App Store, хочу добиться подобной ярости

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя камера (при свете нормально все видно, но когда темнеет, то не очень, не получается сделать ярче камеру):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Да, я знаю, настоящую камеру ночного видения на iPhone сделать не поучится, пытаюсь сделать обычное развлекательное приложение.

Comment: в obj.io есть целый выпуск про камеру. может там что то найдете https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но я видел уже это, с этого сайта начинал изучать камеру